# Duplicate IP Adresses

Tags: ip-address

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Duplicate IP Adresses](https://superuser.com/questions/188313/duplicate-ip-adresses)

My roommate and I have a problem. We have the same IP address. This started a few days ago and I don't know how to change the settings, preferably automatically. He has a desktop and I have a laptop.

Comment: What operating systems do you use? Did either of you do any specific networking configuration? Did you try rebooting, or at least unplugging from the network and plugging back in? What is your network setup (e.g. both connected to <router brand> configured <so>)?

Comment: Duplicate, answered here...http://superuser.com/questions/188313/duplicate-ip-adresses

Answer (score 1):

Just to rule out a basic misconfiguration, go to the command prompt and type

```
ipconfig /renew
```

if this doesn't fix it then, go to Network Connections (Vista/7 go to `Network and sharing Center` then click `Change adapter settings` on the left or in XP, go to `Control Panel` > `Network Connections`).

Now, right click on the adapter you are using and find 'Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4)`.

Make sure automatic is set for at least the top one and your alternate configuration, unless you have a reason to have it manually set.

[image]

If there is a reason you need a manual address (Such as no DHCP source), consider simply changing the last number in the IP to something that no other device is using.